# python NLTK parse subtree

Tags: python, nltk

two questions regarding trees in NLTK:

1. can I differentiate in one tree (sentence) the first, second, ... subtree?
2. how can I work with the tags in the leaves of the subtree?

The following code works good,

```
          for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'NP'):
            for attributes in subtree.leaves():
                print attributes
```

but it returns a list with words and labels:

```
('noun', 'NN')
('verb', VBZ)
```

and so on: 
I need to differentiate between the different types of words within a subtree. 
The subtree.labels() doesnt exist.

Something like:

```
           for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'NP'):
            for attributes in subtree.leaves():
                if subtree.labels() == 'NN':
                  # do something with the nouns...
```

Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

So I did it with python. Anyhow, if someone has a better idea...

```
         for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'NP' or t.node == 'NNS'):
            for attributes in subtree.leaves():
                (expression, tag) = attributes
                if tag == 'NN':
                    # do something with the nouns
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like the following to extract the noun phrases from the tree.

```
from itertools import groupby
[' '.join([t[0] for t,m in group]) for key, group in groupby(tree.pos(), lambda s: s[-1]=='NP') if key]
```

More generally, we can examine what is inside the 'group' and do whatever we want to the element into the group. For example,

```
[list(group]) for key, group in groupby(tree.pos(), lambda s: s[-1]=='NP') if key]
```

Once we know what the element within the 'list(group)' contains, we can do whatever want to with it.

Another way is to use the tree2conlltags. For example,

```
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags
from itertools import groupby

chunks = tree2conlltags(tree)

print(chunks)

results = [' '.join(word for word, pos, chunk in group).lower() for key, group in groupby(chunks, lambda s: s[-1]!='O') if key]
```